# Include Scala project in Java Maven dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, maven

Im new to scala, Im trying to include scala project into my java project.
I have separate scala and java project and Im using scala in java.

It is working fine when I add scalaTest to my java project build path. Is there any way I can edit my pom.xml that automatically refer the scalaTest project while maven build?.

I have added scala dependency in my pom.xml

Or is there any way that I can include both java and scala files into my java project and run ?

[image]

Comment: If you create a jar out of `scalaTest` and deploy it to your local m2 repository, then you should be able to simply add your `scalaTest` project as a dependency to your java project.

Comment: @TillRohrmann, yes that will work. Is there any way that when I maven build this scala project will automatically refer to my java project ?

Comment: is there any way that I can include both java and scala files into my java project and run ?

Answer (score 2):

If you the following `pom.xml` you should be able to compile Java and Scala sources from within the same project via `mvn`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaScala</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>javaScala</name>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDir>src/main/scala</sourceDir>
                    <testSourceDir>src/test/scala</testSourceDir>
                    <jvmArgs>
                        <jvmArg>-Xms64m</jvmArg>
                        <jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
                    </jvmArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

**Answers to my own question**

1. Add Scala project in class path (buildpath) of java project.
2. Export Scala project as jar and import to your java project.

**To include both java and scala in single java project, follow this.**

Include java files into -  src/main/java
Include scala files into -  src/main/scala
Use this pom.xml
Download project from https://github.com/rthoma24/Java-Scala.git

maven commands

> mvn compile
>   mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=main.java.Test

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ted-gao</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-java-mix</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Scala-Java mixture</name>
    <description>Showcase mixing Scala and Java</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- ensure that we use JDK 1.6 -->
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run scala compiler in the process-resources phase, so that dependencies on
                         scala classes can be resolved later in the (Java) compile phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>                        
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        </execution>

                        <!-- Run scala compiler in the process-test-resources phase, so that dependencies on
                             scala classes can be resolved later in the (Java) test-compile phase -->                    
                        <execution>
                        <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Add src/main/scala to source path of Eclipse -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/main/scala</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <!-- Add src/test/scala to test source path of Eclipse -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-test-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/test/scala</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- to generate Eclipse artifacts for projects mixing Scala and Java -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <projectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.scala-ide.sdt.core.scalanature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</projectnature>
                    </projectnatures>
                    <buildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.scala-ide.sdt.core.scalabuilder</buildcommand>
                    </buildcommands>
                    <classpathContainers>
                        <classpathContainer>org.scala-ide.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                        <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                    </classpathContainers>
                    <excludes>
                        <!-- in Eclipse, use scala-library, scala-compiler from the SCALA_CONTAINER rather than POM <dependency> -->
                        <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-library</exclude>
                        <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-compiler</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <sourceIncludes>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.scala</sourceInclude>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.java</sourceInclude>
                    </sourceIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- When run tests in the test phase, include .java and .scala source files -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*.scala</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If mvn install/compile gives any error, delete your m2 directory and try again.